# Testing IE9: Is there a lab I can log into remotely to debug an IE9 issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, testing

Is there a virtual testing center 'in the cloud' that I can remote into to run different configurations of IE9?  I have a heavily modified jquery plugin that some users have reported to be broken in IE9.  However every configuration we have tried we are unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Document compatibility mode? What's the doctype? Have you tested in all the basic IE modes? In IE9, hit F12, change stuff.

Comment: Can you not run IE9 yourself? IE9 supports using the IE7 & IE8 rendering engines... so if you updated to IE9 you can still test IE7 & IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try http://crossbrowsertesting.com - they offer one free hour of testing and there are a variety of OS / IE9 combinations.

The other possibility is browserlabs.com - they don't have OS variants, but do have access to IE debugging tools built in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use any cloud based solutions, but Microsoft provides (free of charge) a test VM for most versions of IE which can be used with VirtualPC. I have found it to be very useful.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 1):

Saucelabs offers 45 mins/month free manual testing:

http://saucelabs.com/pricing